.Net Maui - unable to archive iOS project from Visual Studio 2022
I migrated my mobile app to .Net Maui but unable to archive it to generate .ipa file. I followed this instructions. I click on Publish
It says Failed to create App archive 'xyz' and no error message is displayed(nothing in build comments too). Visual Studio is connect to Mac and I am able to run the app on emulator. Does anyone know where I can find error logs/comments?

Have you successfully created the provisioning profile in the form of distribution? Can you provide a screenshot of the Failed to create App archive 'xyz' screen? Or you can try to generate the .ipa file by using command line, you can refer to Publish an iOS app using the command line.

First, if you generate .ipa files through VS, you need to ensure that:

Create and download the provisioning profile in VS.

In Solution Explorer, navigate to the iOS Bundle Signing tab and ensure that Scheme is set to Manual Provisioning, Signing identity is set to Distribution (Automatic), and Provisioning profile is set to Automatic:


In addition, you can try to generate an ipa file through the command line:

dotnet publish -f net8.0-ios -c Release

. For details, you can refer to Publish an iOS app using the command line.

Thank you, I have provisioning profiles and signings are set correctly. I had to clean, re-build, archive approx 10 times before it successfully archived.
